# sro4m-2 waterproof ultrasonic sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, ultrasonics

I bought this waterproof ultrasonic sensor about 5 of them with the part number SR04M-2 Written on the PCB silkscreen Which is different from the usual SR04t-0.2, they are just not working, I don't know if its using a different communication protocol or its faulty because no output is coming out of the sensor at all.
if anyone out there has ever came across this type and was able to walk his/her way around it should help

Comment: compare the datasheets for the two devices ... which part of your question is about the Arduino?

Comment: Am using arduino to communicate with the sensor and its not working

Comment: there is no information about the arduino in your post ... actually, there is no question being asked ... please add relevant information, such as the sensor datasheet, the connection diagram, the arduino sketch, the description of the expected behavior and the observed  behavior, and the question that you want answered

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. The oscilloscope showed that the output is returned 500us after the digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH), so changing the delay between trigger and pulseIn from 10us to 500us - delayMicroseconds(500), solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found this code for the SRF05 and it works for the SRO4M-2 as well.
Good Luck!

```cpp
const unsigned int TRIG_PIN=13; //RX
const unsigned int ECHO_PIN=12;  TX
const unsigned int BAUD_RATE=9600;

void setup() {
  pinMode(TRIG_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ECHO_PIN, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);  

  const unsigned long duration= pulseIn(ECHO_PIN, HIGH);
  int distance= duration/29/2;
  if(duration==0){
    Serial.println("Warning: no pulse from sensor");
  } else {
    Serial.print("distance to nearest object:");
    Serial.println(distance);
    Serial.println(" cm");
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

RX = trig and TX = Echo  this is counter intuitive but it works. The manufacturer did not bother to indicate trig and echo on the PCB. I discovered this on link : https://bitbucket.org/teckel12/arduino-new-ping/issues/40/aj-sr04m-board.  When I switch RX & TX as indicated in the pics it worked